# Java servlet Security

Tags: java

If the users request to login I will use HTTPS instead of HTTP, then create this token and store it in the cookies and the user can browse easily. 
 Next time the user hit my site he will be logged in automatically using the token my question is if the user used the HTTP instead of HTTPS this means that any hacker can easily spoof the network packets and get the token then fool me, right ? 
 How can I solve this ?

Comment: This seems to be a better question for [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/). :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [HttpCookie.setSecure(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setSecure%28boolean%29).

Comment: But this means that I should always use HTTPS to secure the login am I right ?